# Is there a way to skip trash on deleting hdfs files via pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I'm using `delete` from `org.apache.hadoop.fs` package to exclude some HDFS files. But I don't want to move them to my user's trash folder, I want to permanently delete all. How can I do this?

Below is an example of my code:

```py
fs = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(self.spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())

fs.delete(self.fileSystem.Path('my/dir/'))
```